# oracle ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype without using LONG datatype

Tags: oracle

I need to extract a single row from two views using a flag from a parent view to determinate which one to query
Just to focus the case:

```
declare
    rowRetrived v_child_A%rowtype;
for key in (select value1, value2, value3, flag from v_parent_view) loop
    if flag = 'A' then
        select * into rowRetrived
        from v_child_A 
        where field1 = key.value1
        and field2 = key.value2
        and field3 = key.value3;
    end if;
    if flag = 'B' then
        select * into rowRetrived -- **** HERE THE ERROR IS RAISED ****
        from v_child_B 
        where field1 = key.value1
        and field2 = key.value2
        and field3 = key.value3;
    end if;
    doStuff(rowRetrived);
end loop;
...
```

I do not use the LONG datatype anywhere and I check that the two child views has the same fields and same types. I am struggling quite hard on this issue because I do not know how to debug it.

Some considerations:

- both v_child_A and v_child_B work either without or with filters (eg: the where clause is `where filed1 = 'value1' and field2 = 'value2' and field3 = 'value3'`)
- although the views's structure is the same I try declaring two distinct rowtype varables but the error is still raised

****** EDIT ******

Here follow the actual descriptions of views

**V_PARENT_VIEW**

```
ID_DISTRIBUZIONE    NUMBER  22
ID_TRAGITTO_DISTR   VARCHAR2    40
PROGR_TRAGITTO  NUMBER  22
SHIP_OU_ID  VARCHAR2    15
ACCNT_NAME  VARCHAR2    100
ROW_ID_DEST VARCHAR2    15
EDITO   NUMBER  22
EXTRA   NUMBER  22
```

**v_child_A**

```
ID_DISTRIBUZIONE    NUMBER  22
COD_DESTINATARIO    VARCHAR2    100
ID_DESTINATARIO VARCHAR2    15
DESTINATARIO    VARCHAR2    50
RIGA_LOCALITA   VARCHAR2    50
INDIRIZZO   VARCHAR2    50
FRAZIONE    VARCHAR2    50
PRESSO  VARCHAR2    50
PVUFF   NUMBER  22
NOTA_CONSEGNA   VARCHAR2    100
TEL_DESTINATARIO    VARCHAR2    20
FUNZIONARIO VARCHAR2    30
TEL_FUNZIONARIO VARCHAR2    20
RIGA_LOCALITA_DEST  VARCHAR2    50
INDIRIZZO_DEST  VARCHAR2    50
FRAZIONE_DEST   VARCHAR2    50
PRESSO_DEST VARCHAR2    50
TRASPORTATORE   VARCHAR2    50
ID_DISTRIBUTORE VARCHAR2    15
ID_TRAGITTO_DISTR   VARCHAR2    40
PROGR_TRAGITTO  NUMBER  22
CONS_FATTURA    NUMBER  22
NUMERO_VERDE_TEL    VARCHAR2    20
SERVIZIO_CLIENTI_FAX    VARCHAR2    20
SERVIZIO_CLIENTI_TEL    VARCHAR2    20
SERVIZIO_CLIENTI_EMAIL  VARCHAR2    20
CANALE  VARCHAR2    100
ID_PROVINCIA    NUMBER  22
ID_REGIONE  NUMBER  22
ID_NAZIONE  NUMBER  22
CAPOLUOGO   NUMBER  22
PROVINCIA   VARCHAR2    2
ROW_ID_DEST VARCHAR2    15
POSIZIONE   VARCHAR2    50
```

**v_child_B**

```
ID_DISTRIBUZIONE    NUMBER  22
COD_DESTINATARIO    VARCHAR2    100
ID_DESTINATARIO VARCHAR2    15
DESTINATARIO    VARCHAR2    50
RIGA_LOCALITA   VARCHAR2    50
INDIRIZZO   VARCHAR2    50
FRAZIONE    VARCHAR2    50
PRESSO  VARCHAR2    50
PVUFF   NUMBER  22
NOTA_CONSEGNA   VARCHAR2    200
TEL_DESTINATARIO    VARCHAR2    20
FUNZIONARIO VARCHAR2    30
TEL_FUNZIONARIO VARCHAR2    20
RIGA_LOCALITA_DEST  VARCHAR2    50
INDIRIZZO_DEST  VARCHAR2    50
FRAZIONE_DEST   VARCHAR2    50
PRESSO_DEST VARCHAR2    50
TRASPORTATORE   VARCHAR2    50
ID_DISTRIBUTORE VARCHAR2    15
ID_TRAGITTO_DISTR   VARCHAR2    40
PROGR_TRAGITTO  NUMBER  22
CONS_FATTURA    NUMBER  22
NUMERO_VERDE_TEL    VARCHAR2    20
SERVIZIO_CLIENTI_FAX    VARCHAR2    20
SERVIZIO_CLIENTI_TEL    VARCHAR2    20
SERVIZIO_CLIENTI_EMAIL  VARCHAR2    20
CANALE  VARCHAR2    100
ID_PROVINCIA    NUMBER  22
ID_REGIONE  NUMBER  22
ID_NAZIONE  NUMBER  22
CAPOLUOGO   NUMBER  22
PROVINCIA   VARCHAR2    2
ROW_ID_DEST VARCHAR2    15
POSIZIONE   VARCHAR2    50
```

Comment: Pls post the result of `select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH from user_tab_columns where table_name in ( 'V_CHILD_A', 'V_CHILD_B') order by TABLE_NAME,column_id;`.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber : I edit as requested. I am sorry for the poor documentation

Comment: I wonder if the different length of the column `NOTA_CONSEGNA` could cause this. But I would expect a different error message is `v_child_b.NOTA_CONSEGNA` contains more than 100 characters (or bytes)

Comment: Yes, this raise `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`. I suspect you must go in the view definition and check if there aren't some suspect transformation. Try to find with exclusion method which column is causing the error.